# O que é um client-side prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou começando a desenvolver uma página utilizando PHP e, como ainda estou conhecendo a linguagem, resolvi buscar qual módulo utilizar para fazer a conexão com uma base de dados MySQL.

A partir [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/582/1333), descobri que o módulo `mysql_*` já foi descontinuado e contém vários problemas de segurança. Na mesma resposta ele indica o uso da [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) e do [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php), como fiquei em dúvida fui comparar as [diferenças entre as duas](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Isso me deixou mais confuso ainda, pois a `mysqli_*` parece oferecer bem mais suporte do que a `PDO`, no entanto só a `PDO` oferece suporte a `client-side prepared statements`.

Minha dúvida é qual a diferença entre *prepared statements* server-side e client-side? Quando utilizar um e quando utilizar o outro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A driver PDO é uma camada de abstraccao, e nao está associada a nenhuma BD relacional especifica. Esta camada simula prepared statements do lado do cliente, no caso de o servidor nao suportar prepared statements.

A biblioteca `mysqli` é uma camada especifica para bases de dados MySQL. Como as bases de dados MySQL suportam prepared statements do lado do servidor, não há necessidade de as simular.

Resumidamente, usa server-side prepared statements sempre que possivel. A simulacao do lado do cliente so e' util quando o proprio servidor nao e' capaz de o fazer.

Usa PDO sempre que quiseres a camada de abstraccao extra - ou seja, se nao quiseres que o codigo fique dependente de uma BD especifica - ou, como referido pelo @bfavaretto, quiseres usar parametros nomeados.

Comment: Tem mais uma diferença no caso do MySQL: com o PDO é possível usar parâmetros nomeados no prepared statemente (`WHERE foo = :bar`), que o MySQL não suporta nativamente.

Comment: Então, no caso de uma base de dados MySQL, o ideal é utilizar o mysqli_*?

Comment: Depende da complexidade desejada. Se as minhas queries fossem complexas o suficiente, eu usaria `mysqli` (para obter mais flexibilidade), e criava a minha propria camada de abstraccao usando o padrao [Adapter](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html).

Comment: @felipe.avelar O PDO traz a vantagem de ser portável entre diferentes tipos de SGBDs, hoje você está usando MySQL e amanhã você muda pra Oracle e só vai precisar mudar a linha de código onde você diz pro PDO qual é o tipo de SGBD. O MySQLi é ligeiramente mais rápido, mas a diferença é praticamente irrelevante. Pessoalmente eu uso MySQLi, mas é por questão de gosto mesmo.

Comment: @felipe.avelar Ah sim, é mais seguro usar Persistent Connections com o MySQLi. Ele faz um cleanup automático caso sua aplicação falhe no meio de uma transação, já o PDO não. Se uma transação terminar sem COMMIT/ROLLBACK, a próxima página vai continuar dentro da mesma transação, isso pode ser um problema grave.